# ggplot2 stat_density_2d not working properly when grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a dataset of city houses. Each house is in one region. You can have the dataset [here](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/melbourne-housing-snapshot), and below is a graph of the city with its regions.

```
raw_csv = read.csv("melb_data.csv")

ggplot(raw_csv, aes(Lattitude, Longtitude)) + geom_point(aes(color = Regionname))
```

[image]

When I use `stat_density_2d` it works OK. Here is a picture of the result.

```
ggplot(raw_csv, aes(Lattitude, Longtitude)) + stat_density_2d()
```

[image]

But the problem is when I group `stat_density_2d` to regions. It does not work properly. I want the density of each region separately (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282989/show-only-high-density-areas-with-ggplot2s-stat-density-2d), but it doesn't work).

Here is the weird result of grouping it.

```
ggplot(raw_csv, aes(Lattitude, Longtitude)) + stat_density_2d(aes(group = Regionname))
```

[image]

Where am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
It is very strange! but when I excluded the region "Western Victoria" from the map, others went OK. I still don't understand what is the problem here.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

As I'm not familiar with `stat_density_2d` I can't tell you what's going wrong with the grouping. However, as a workaround you could split your data frame by region and add a density layer for each region separately where I make use of lapply to loop over the splitted df:

```
library(ggplot2)

split_csv <- split(raw_csv, raw_csv$Regionname)

ggplot(mapping = aes(Lattitude, Longtitude, color = Regionname)) + 
  lapply(split_csv, function(x) stat_density_2d(data = x))
```

[image]